# Its like transpose rows to columns in DB2 while we can't use aggregation

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I have a table as below

Element Value

State   GA
State   CA
State   IL

And so on ....

I need to transpose above output as follows. It's similar to transposing, but little different as I need comma separated columns.

Element Value

State   GA,CA,IL

Can someone help me to achieve above result in db2?

Comment: Please provide more information such as table names, column names, and schema

Comment: thanks @mustaccio . That really helped.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer with the help of @mustaccio
used listagg function..